# How to delete or edit only one row in sql table?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pycharm, mysql-workbench

[that is my app and I used search button to edit information easily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAz2x.png) I used that code in python to add, delete , update info to local database ....It runs well in adding info but when I use update all information or rows in database become the same . Also, when delete all data deleted perhaps due to using one search bar to bring added data to be edited or deleted

This is my code :

```
import sys
import os
import time

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"mahmoudtarek.ui"))

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Main,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.InitUI()
        self.conn = None

        self.handle_buttons()
        self.handle_db_connections()

    def InitUI(self):
        ## changes in the run time
        pass

    def handle_buttons(self):
          ## all buttons in the app
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_mahmoud_friends)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.update_mahmoud_friends)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.delete_mahmoud_friends)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.search_mahmoud_friends)


    def handle_db_connections(self):
        try:
            self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                host='127.0.0.1',
                database='mydb',
                user='root',
                password='134668691011',
                use_pure=True)  # use_pure is set to true

            if self.conn.is_connected():
                db_Info = self.conn.get_server_info()
                print("Connected to MySQL database using C extension... MySQL Server version on ", db_Info)
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print("Error while connecting to MySQL using C extension", err)

    def add_mahmoud_friends(self):
        mth_friends = self.lineEdit.text()
        mth_search = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        if self.conn:
            c = self.conn.cursor()
            try:
                c.execute('''INSERT INTO ahmed (mth_friends,mth_search) values (%s,%s)''', (mth_friends,mth_search))
                self.conn.commit()
                self.lineEdit.setText('')
                self.lineEdit_4.setText('')
                self.statusBar.showMessage('ok mahmoud')


            except mysql.connector.Error as err:
                print("Error: ", err)

    def update_mahmoud_friends(self):
        mth_friends = self.lineEdit.text()
        mth_search = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        if self.conn:
            c = self.conn.cursor()
            try:
                c.execute('''UPDATE ahmed SET mth_friends = %s,mth_search = %s''', (mth_friends, mth_search))
                self.conn.commit()
                self.lineEdit.setText('')
                self.lineEdit_4.setText('')
                self.statusBar.showMessage('ok mahmoud')
                self.lineEdit_3.setText('')


            except mysql.connector.Error as err:
                print("Error: ", err)

    def delete_mahmoud_friends(self):
        c = self.conn.cursor()
        sql = '''DELETE FROM ahmed WHERE mth_search = %s'''
        mth_search = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        c.execute(sql, [(mth_search)])
        self.conn.commit()
        self.statusBar.showMessage("ok")
        self.lineEdit.setText('')
        self.lineEdit_4.setText('')
        self.lineEdit_3.setText('')


    def search_mahmoud_friends(self):
        if self.conn:
            c = self.conn.cursor()

            try:

                sql = '''SELECT * FROM ahmed WHERE mth_search = %s'''
                mth_search = self.lineEdit_3.text()
                c.execute(sql, [(mth_search)])
                data = c.fetchall()
                for row in data :
                    print(row)
                    self.lineEdit.setText(str(row[1]))
                    self.lineEdit_4.setText(str(row[2]))

            except mysql.connector.Error as err:
              print("Error: ", err)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.conn:
            self.conn.close()
        super(Main, self).closeEvent(event)


def main():
    app= QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window =Main()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I need help in that as I'm still a beginner  If someone knew the problem , please write me the corrected code . As I searched too much ...and last thank you

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` queries that tells it which rows to update.

Comment: "You need a `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` queries that tells it which rows to update"  @Barmar Don't forget the primary or unique keys tho because the topicstarter only want to `DELETE` or `UPDATE` one record

Comment: That's just a specific case, where he knows the ID of the row he wants to update. It could be a condition like all the rows for the same friend.

Comment: what I must write in that condition ....give me example please

Answer (score 1):

When you `UPDATE`, you need to add a condition, otherwise every row in the table is going to be updated with those values.

In your code:

```
c.execute('''UPDATE ahmed SET mth_friends = %s,mth_search = %s''', (mth_friends, mth_search))
```

Should have a condition, like this:

```
c.execute('''UPDATE ahmed SET mth_friends = %s,mth_search = %s WHERE {ADD CONDITION HERE}''', (mth_friends, mth_search))
```

If you want to update or delete a **single** row, you want the condition to match a primary key or unique key column. Using a condition involving any other type of column will update or delete all rows matching that condition. (Thanks to [Raymond Nijland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2548147/raymond-nijland))

Comment: Without the `WHERE` clause matching a primary or unique keys columns the `UPDATE` can still update multiple records.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you, I edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: please give me an example of that condition as I do not understand

Comment: @mthafize19 In your table, there should be an integer column with the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint. That column uniquely identifies each row with an ID. If you want to update a single row, the condition must match that row's ID in the `PRIMARY KEY` column. For example: if you want to update the row where the ID is 5, the condition would be `WHERE ID = 5`

Comment: I set id in mysql workbench as auto increment , so when I add much data I must return to code and write its id condition....How is that ? .....there must be another way. @rdimaio

Comment: @mthafize19 I am not sure what your question is. Auto increment just means that the ID of each row is automatically set without you having to add it manually. Whenever you `UPDATE` a row, you first need to find the unique ID of that particular row, and then you can write the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: @rdimaio I used the condition for example id = 5 ....its row become edited successfully ...but there is more id in the table and added data has its unique id so, each time I add data I must go back to the code and add new row id with the last one to be edited alone

Comment: @rdimaio I edited my comment above it works but the problem still other new added rows, which I don't write its id , have the problem

Comment: @rdimaio I added a screenshot of my app in my Q post